# Unable to start new activity onItemClick in recyclerview Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewmodel

I've a recyclerview which using viewmodel to view items. But when I click the item it's not clicking/starting new activity.

Adapter class:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Search> arrayList;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private MovieAdapterListener listener;

    public MovieAdapter(ArrayList<Search> arrayList, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (layoutInflater==null){
            layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        }
        MyListBinding myListBinding= DataBindingUtil.inflate(layoutInflater, R.layout.mylist,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(myListBinding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Search myListViewModel=movieListFiltered.get(position);
        holder.bind(myListViewModel);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movieListFiltered.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private MyListBinding myListBinding;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull MyListBinding myListBinding) {
            super(myListBinding.getRoot());
            this.myListBinding=myListBinding;
        }
        public void bind(Search myli){
            this.myListBinding.setMylistmodel(myli);
            myListBinding.executePendingBindings();
        }
        public MyListBinding getMyListBinding(){
            return myListBinding;
        }
    }

    public interface MovieAdapterListener {
        void onMovieSelected(Search movieSearch);
    }
}
```

Then I created below in the MainActivity

```
@Override
    public void onMovieSelected(Search movie) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.Title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MovieDetailsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("IMDB_ID", movie.Title);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

When I click on the item nothing happening. Can someone help me?

Comment: Provide whole code of adapter. Where have you pass your `MovieAdapterListener` to adapter?

Comment: Is toast displaying the expected output?

Comment: @Marat: complete adapter attached above

Comment: @Karrthik no nothing showing. if you need full MainActivity code please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be better to implement OnClickListener on your ViewHolder class and add the listener to your desired views.

Just in onBindViewHolder(...) add setOnClickListener(...) like this:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

//... 

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), movie.Title, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MovieDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("IMDB_ID", movie.Title);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
});}
```

Comment: Getting error in Intent(this, MovieDetailsActivity.class);

Comment: if you implement this above..what you are getting error?

Comment: instead of this use "getcontext()" or "getApplicationContext()"